# How do I read a certain string on a line from a file, using scanner?

Tags: java, string, delimiter

I'm trying to read a text file which looks like this:

A,32,0,0,0,0

And right now I have a static method which reads from that file. I'm getting this NoSuchElement exception, while earlier I had a Mismatch exception.

May I ask what I'm missing in this code? I'm sorry for the vagueness.

```
public static ArrayList<RaceCar> readCar(String s, Track raceTrack)throws IOException,FileNotFoundException
 {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("CarData.txt"));
     sc.useDelimiter(",");
     String exists;
     ArrayList<RaceCar> racers = new  ArrayList<RaceCar>();

    while ((exists = sc.nextLine()) != null) 
    {
         String dName = sc.next();
         int dNum = sc.nextInt();
         int dWins = sc.nextInt();
         int dRunUp = sc.nextInt();
         int dRaces = sc.nextInt();

         racers.add(new RaceCar(dName,dNum,raceTrack,dWins,dRunUp,dRaces));
    }   

    return racers;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
sc.nextLine()
```

with

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
  //code
}
```

By calling nextLine all your data for that line in your file is in `exists`.

Take a look at the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

What do you need the exists-String for?

Try:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
   // ...
}
```